# TENGO PROBLEMAS USANDO FORM REPEATER

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy usando el jquery-repeater, este es mi modal donde lo estoy usando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se nos damos cuenta en la imagen, el primer select se llena correctamente(recalcar que el selectse llena desde un controller), pero al añadir el segundo select me muestra vacio.

este es mi codigo js para el repeater:

```
$(function () {
// form repeater Initialization
$('.repeater-default').repeater({
    initEmpty: false,
    
    show: function () {
        $(this).slideDown();
        console.log("Nuevo elemento mostrado:", this);
        cargarHabitaciones($(this)); // Pasar el contexto del nuevo elemento al cargarHabitaciones
    },
    hide: function (deleteElement) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
            $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
        }
    }
    
}).on('ready', function () {
    cargarHabitaciones($(this));
});
```

});

este es la forma en el que llene el select:

```
 // select para reservas
$.post("../controller/htl_recepcion.php?op=select_habitaciones",
    { token: token },
    function (data) {
        $("#select_reserva_habitaciones").html(data);
    });
```

estuve intentando de varias formas pero no me sale, por eso agregue la funcion cargarHabitaciones();

este es el codigo de la funcion:

```
function cargarHabitaciones(context) {
$.post("../controller/htl_recepcion.php?op=select_habitaciones",
    { token: token },
    function (data) {
        console.log("Datos recibidos:", data);
        context.find(".select_reserva_habitaciones").html(data);
```

Comment: esto que tiene que ver con php????